# Cassandra Datastax connection pooling monitor/metrics

Tags: java, cassandra, connection-pooling, datastax-java-driver

my team is moving from using Astyanax driver (which is deprecated soon if not already) to using Datastax 3.0 driver.

Our code implements Astyanax's ConnectionPoolMonitor class and we capture about 22 different metrics on our connection pool usage.

I am trying to find an equivalent way to do this with Datastax driver. But all I could find is this:
https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/pooling/#monitoring-and-tuning-the-pool

Basically, the example above shows how you can run a background thread that continuously polls Session.State. This seems rather awkward. Astyanax does  callbacks to the classes that implement ConnectionPoolMonitor.

And the amount of info exposed in Session.State is rather limited: connected hosts, inflight queries, open connections, and trashed connections.

Is there a better option out there that I haven't found somehow? How can I capture metrics such as these:

- count of when Pool is exhausted, got connection timeout, socket timeout, got not hosts
- count of connection created, closed, borrowed, returned, creation error
- count of host added, removed, down, reactivated/reconnected
- count of exception unknown error, bad request, interrupted, transport error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cluster.getMetrics()` and read this Java doc: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Metrics.html